# Entity Framework no key

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

There is key attribute when specifying context class of some object. In my case don't have primary key in table. Unfortunately entity try to force me to make key attribute on context class field. What can I do to avoid that?

Comment: Add a primary key to your table - ***every*** relational table **ought to have one** to begin with

Comment: i know this option i am looking to workaround this

Comment: There **is no workaround** - it is a **very fundamental** design principle: you **must be able** to uniquely identify each row in your table. If you don't have a primary key in your table, your design is horribly bad. Don't do this! Don't search for ways around this principle - **embrace and live it!!**

Comment: i know its pinciple and must pattern but in mz case i how to do it this waz so mz question is whether possible or not?

Comment: ***NO*** - Entity Framework **must have** something to uniquely identify each row. It ***must have*** a primary key. Stop wasting your time trying to circumvent this - just add the primary key to your table and be done with it

Comment: in my case besides table pk i would have to change lot of code. but ok thanks for asnwers